# Group rows without invoking an aggregate function

Tags: t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions

I read this sentence on a exam book

> You can group rows without invoking an aggregate function.

Can anyone give me an example of this?

Comment: We need more context here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this homework ? Here is a group by with no aggregate function

```
select a, b
from table
group by a,b
```

Result will be the same as this:

```
select distinct a, b
from table
```